# Automatically update details of approval in Power Automate flow

Tags: sharepoint, power-automate

I have a list of pdf files in SharePoint for approval.
There are approval comments 1 - 4. 4 approvals are required.
Of course, there will be showing all the comments after that file has been all approved BUT at the process of approving the comments of approval will not be showing in the approval detail. If I try to add Comments in Detail that will become a nested "Apply to each" like "Apply to each 5".

[image]

How to do that in each detail of Approval with Expression or something else? ( If I use Comments in Detail that will become a nested "Apply for each")

Thanks.

Comment: So how to make all approval comments showing in approval detail when they submit the decision and comment?

Answer (score 0):

This is because an approval can be assigned to mutliple users, (there may be multiple approval reponses) so you need an Apply to Each on the Responses element. If you assign the approval to only one user, just ignore the nested "Apply to each".

Comment: Thank you. That is only the reason but how to make all approval comments added to approval detail every time when they submit comment.

Comment: Will there be nested of nested two or three levels of nested in 2nd, 3rd and 4 approval? If not how to do that? I heard that I can use the expression to do that and how?

Comment: How to get the answer how to do that. Thank you.